# How to use truncate helper in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

How to use truncate helper in rails views for the following text
My requirement is

1. Truncate after 20 letters.(Length = 20)
2. On the hover of the link, the full text should be displayed

html.erb

```
<%= link_to sta.device_app.prog_ser.adsp.name, reports_revenue_index_path(:adsp_id => sta.device_app.adsp.id) %>
```

I tried. But my ideas didn't work out. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest this:

```
<%= link_to truncate(sta.device_app.prog_ser.adsp.name, :length => 20, :tooltip => sta.device_app.prog_ser.adsp.name), reports_revenue_index_path(:adsp_id => sta.device_app.adsp.id), title: sta.device_app.prog_ser.adsp.name %>
```